# GDAL offline load of WMS

Tags: gdal, wms

I'm loading a WMS map using gdal.

Online access works fine, including cache. The cache looks fine, I can see the files and open the images.

When I try to load the same WMS in offline mode it works, but only if I use the same coordinates.

My issue is to open the map in offline mode for different coordinates that **overlaps** with the cached area. (It's ok if the area outside my cache would be black)

Sample Xml for the request as described in the [gdal doc](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html), the problem can be reproduced changing `OfflineMode` to `true` and changing the coordinates:

```xml
<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="WMS">
        <Version>1.1.1</Version>
        <ServerUrl>https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?</ServerUrl>
        <Layers>OSM-WMS</Layers>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <SizeX>500</SizeX>
        <SizeY>500</SizeY>
        <UpperLeftX>9.892920</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>50.626900</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>13.978200</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>47.082800</LowerRightY>
    </DataWindow>
    <Cache>
        <Path>./gdalwmscache</Path>
        <Depth>2</Depth>
        <Extension>.jpg</Extension>
    </Cache>
    <OfflineMode>false</OfflineMode>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Answer (score 0):

GDal uses a hash of the request URL, internally generated, to create a cache structure.

When making a request with for a different area, the request URL is different from before, so the hash is also different and there is no cache match in most of the cases.

Obs: WMTS has fixed URLs, so it's possible to use the cache even when requesting areas with different bounding boxes.